# how to disable Cloudflare SSL for only one page in a website?

Tags: cloudflare

I want to avoid Cloudflare SSL from only one page of a website. I am using flexible SSL and I cant change it other. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a page rule in the Cloudflare dashboard.

Go to **Page Rules**, look for **SSL condition** and you can there change it to **Off, Flexible, Full or Strict**.

Comment: I dont want to change in between flexible, full or strict. I need it to be flexible. And What I want is to remove ssl from only one page say `https://example.com/specificurl.html`. And all other pages need ssl.

Comment: On the page rule, you establish the SSL condition for OFF explicitely to your url, for example: https://example.com/specificurl.html

Comment: I already tried it, but page reloads continuosely, nothing happens. See [here](https://i.ibb.co/rMqHbHY/Screenshot-from-2020-03-23-14-02-43.png)

Comment: The order of rules is important. Try moving that rule from the second position to the first.

Comment: Also not sure but maybe the rule must be defined without the https? My guess is you need to rewrite those that go to your https to 301 redirect to http for it to work properly.